# How to Sum Price from 6:00am till next day 6:00am

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to sum price from current day `6:00am` till next day `6:00am` (`24hour`). The problem is what if will run my code from `6:00am` till `24:00(00:00)` and what if I will run it from `24:01` till `6:00am`?

Should I create two exceptions for this or I can run it with one code?

My `Sql` Table Contains a `DateTime` column.

```
    var date = DateTime.Now;
            if ((date.Hour>=6&& date.Minute >0) && (date.Hour <= 24 && date.Minute < 59))
            {

            }
else if ((date.Hour>=0&& date.Minute >0) && (date.Hour <= 5 && date.Minute < 59))
            {

            }
```

Or if I can do it immediately with a `sql` query?

```
SELECT SUM(sumtotal) from customertrans where DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime)>=6 and DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime)<=24 and DATEPART(HOUR, DateTime)=DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())
```

If hour is from `24:00` till `6:00` I need to add also the previous day from `6:00` am till `24:00`

Check this approch below:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
        if ((date.Hour >= 6 && date.Minute >= 0) && (date.Hour <= 23 && date.Minute <= 59))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sum(sumTotal) from customertrans where datetime>='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00') ", con);
            string test = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(test);
        }
        else if ((date.Hour >= 0 && date.Minute >= 0) && (date.Hour <= 5 && date.Minute <= 59))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sum(sumTotal) datetime from customertrans where datetime>='" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and DateTime >= DATEPART(HOUR, '6:00') ", con);
            string test = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(test);
        }
```

Comment: You will need an if statement somehow but in TSQL you can still do this. What you need is to first pick 6am today. Then you need to check if that 6am is before or after your current time. If it's before then that 6am become your start range and your current time is the end range. If the 6 am is after your current time then that is the end range and start range is 24 hours before

Answer (score 1):

> from current day 6:00am till next day 6:00am (24hour)

Not true. Some days have 23:00 and others have 25:00, so bear that in mind. Given that you are calling this from C#, I find it a bit odd that you are doing stuff with DATEPART. Why not just do a ranged query on DateTime? If the field is indexed then you will avoid a table scan.

Why not something like:

```
        TimeSpan cutoverTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(6); // or however you have this defined

    // DateTime.Now is unstable, and the date may change between two consecutive calls
    // so read it into a temporary variable

    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startTime = currentTime.Date.Add(cutoverTime); // guess today
    if (startTime > currentTime)
    {
        // ok, guessed wrong, it was yesterday
        startTime = startTime.AddDays(-1);          
    }       
    DateTime endTime = startTime.AddDays(1);

    // And use parametised queries, not string concatenation (please)
    // SELECT SUM(sumtotal) from customertrans where DateTime >= @startTime and DateTime < @endTime
```

A further word of caution, you need to probably be thinking about timezones, maybe doing something with respect to UTCNow instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your where statement.

```
WHERE date BETWEEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy') + ' 06:00' AND FORMAT(GETDATE() + 1, 'MM/dd/yyyy') + ' 06:00'
```

This formats the current date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format then appends the time of 6:00 am to it (for start date), then does the same but adds `1` (which adds `1` day) to it to get tomorrows date.

For `SQL 2008` you can do this:

```
where date BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + ' 06:00' AND  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() + 1, 110) + ' 06:00'
```

Comment: What if i will run this code the hour will be 3:00am in midnight? I need to sum also previous date?

Comment: this is wrong. if it's 2 am on april 5th it gives april 5th 6am to april 6th 6am when it should give april 4th 6am to april 5th 6am.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DateTime start = date.Date.AddHours(6);
if ((date.Hour >= 6 && date.Minute >= 0) && (date.Hour <= 23 && date.Minute <= 59))
{
     sum = Sum(start, start.AddDays(1));
}
else if ((date.Hour >= 0 && date.Minute >= 0) && (date.Hour <= 5 && date.Minute <= 59))
{
     sum = Sum(start.AddDays(-1), start);
}
```

Where your sum method is declared like

```
public int Sum(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

Comment: Ok i will try it. Actually i will add sql qeries inside the exceptions